# How come all rational functions can be decomposed into partial fractions?

Tags: polynomials, partial-fractions

Why is it guaranteed that *all* rational functions $\frac{R(x)}{Q(x)}$, where the degree of $R$ is less than $Q$, can be written as the sum of partial fractions of the form $\frac{Ax + B}{(ax^2+bx+c)^i}$? For example, the simple case
$$
\frac{P(x)}{(x+a)(x+b)}=\frac{A}{x+a}+\frac{B}{x+b}\\
\implies P(x) = A(x+b) + B(x+a)
$$
This example reminds me of the concept of linear independence from Linear Algebra, perhaps this statement is true because $(x+b)$ and $(x+a)$ are not multiples of each other, and therefore some linear combination of them has to equal $P(x)$.

Stewart's Calculus only says that "a theorem in algebra guarantees that it is always possible to do this." I've tried reading the proofs found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) and from [this previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3132111/use-algebra-to-prove-all-proper-rational-function-can-be-written-in-partial-frac) but I'm having a hard time understanding them.

Comment: Every polynomial can be expressed as a product of linear factors.

Comment: All polynomials $(x-a)^i$ and $(x^2+px+q)^i$ with $p^2<4q$ are linearly independent. Every polynomial with real coefficients can be factorized to such polynomials.

Comment: Collect coefficients by powers of $x$.  There are as many powers as one more than the degree of $P$.  This gives a linear system of $1 + \deg P$ equations.  Each factor $(q_i(x))^{r_i}$ in the denominator (under $P$) gives $-1 + \deg q_i$ unknowns in the numerator.  A theorem of algebra is that the denominator has such a factorization (into linear factors of various powers, if we allow complex coefficients, into irreducible not-necessarily-linear factors if we stick to real coefficients).

Comment: well, any polynomial with real coefficients can be written as a product of real quadratics, also some linears if there happen to be real roots. This fact is just the observation, for a complex root $\alpha,$  that $(x - \alpha)(x - \bar{\alpha}) = x^2 -2Ux + W,$ where $U,W$  are real

Comment: In the simple case, the space of rational functions of the form $\frac{C_1 x + C_2}{(x+a)(x+b)}$ is a vector space of dimension 2; and the 2 elements $\frac{1}{x+a} = \frac{x+b}{(x+a)(x+b)}$ and $\frac{1}{x+b} = \frac{x+a}{(x+a)(x+b)}$ are linearly independent (if $\frac{A}{x+a} + \frac{B}{x+b} = 0$, then $A(x+b) + B(x+a) = 0$; now substitute $x=-a$ to see $A = 0$ and $x=-b$ to see $B=0$).  Therefore, they also span the vector space.